# Oracle Linux - Java Stuck Thread Alarm Script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to edit a WebLogic Server stuck thread alarm script to run on Linux operating systems (specifically Oracle Linux and RHEL).

I saw various scripts on the web and made some edits to prepare them as follows.

My goal is to find the total number of stuck threads via `jstack` and, if the number is more than 0, to send an e-mail with the stuck thread details for each Java process separately (with managed server name). If there is no stuck thread, write `OKAY` to the file and wait for the script to run again.

```bash
checkstucklog=/home/weblogic/lastStuckCheck.log
DATE=`date +"%Y_%m_%d %H:%M:%S"`
#count="$(ps -ef | grep Dweblogic | cut -c 10-15 | tr -d ' ' | xargs jstack -F | tee /home/weblogic/msALL_stuck.log_`/usr/bin/date +\%m-\%d-\%y-\%H-\%M` | grep STUCK | wc -l)"
count="$(ps -ef | grep Dweblogic | cut -c 10-15 | tr -d ' ' | xargs jstack -F -l | tee /home/weblogic/msALL_stuck_$DATE.log | grep STUCK | wc -l)"

if [ $count > 0 ]
then
  echo "\n Server has stuck threads" `/usr/bin/date +\%m-\%d-\%y-\%H-\%M` | mail -s 'STUCK thread on server' your_mail_address@mail_address.com > $Sfile
else
  echo "\n Stuck Thread Status = OKAY" > $checkstucklog
fi
exit
```

However, I am a little weak in bash scripting. Can you please help me make the following script work properly?

- Is the way I write the script correct?
- Can I produce another alternative instead of Tee?

I could not confirm the functionality of this script because there is no stuck thread yet. But I don't think it will work. I couldn't find how to print the managed server name by finding it from the OS process.

Comment: On the end of count line you have `grep STUCK | grep wc -l`. Is this a mistake or it is intentional?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Hello Romeo, intentional. I want to find STUCK threads.

Comment: The command do not make much sense, it must be: `grep STUCK | wc -l`

Comment: @RomeoNinov I missed it, thank you. Do you have any other comments for my questions? Does it work this way?

Comment: The command `jstack` may not accept `-F` You will need long listing only if you want to keep track in log about the stack traces. Also the variable `DATE` have space in the value so this may broke the log creation. Better use `DATE=$(date +"%Y_%m_%d.%H:%M:%S")`

Comment: Also when compare numbers in `if` the recommended way is `[ "$count" -gt 0 ]`

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to point you to some points you should reconsider:

in line:

```
count="$(ps -ef | grep Dweblogic | cut -c 10-15 | tr -d ' ' | xargs jstack -F -l | tee /home/weblogic/msALL_stuck_$DATE.log | grep STUCK | wc -l)"
```

you use variable `DATE` which have space inside. Will be better if you generate it on this way (using other character instead of space)

```
DATE=`date +"%Y_%m_%d_%H:%M:%S"`
```

Also you can rewrite the command with `awk` to strip some commands:

```
count="$(ps -ef | awk '/Dweblogic/ {print $2}' | xargs jstack -F -l | tee /home/weblogic/msALL_stuck_$DATE.log | grep STUCK | wc -l)"
```

About `jstack` command: as you use Weblogic will be wise to use Oracle java (same company products). And in Oracle java `jstack` do not have the option `-F`.

I know Oracle java is commercial product, but as far as I remember if you use Oracle product (WebLogic in this case) you can use java for free. But will be better to contact your legal department about this case (to check the license agreement).

When you compare numbers in `bash` the recommended form is:

```
if [ "$count" -gt 0 ]
```

And good practice is to put variables in double quotes, especially when they are dynamically generated